# Load an Iframe with web workers (Angular)

Tags: angular, iframe, webforms, web-worker

I have an Angular application that hosts an Iframe with a Webforms page inside.
Now the complete loading process untill the page including the Iframe has finished is to long. I have thought if there is a way to load the Iframe parallel with the help of web workers.
Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Stupid question probably, but do you really need an iframe? :-)

Comment: I also thought about using an ajax load and add the result into a div, but WebForms are server rendered and use server side methods, also you need to include all the scripts that are used by the webforms application.